# In TortoiseSVN, can Merge-conflicts occur also after resolving the Update-conflicts?

Tags: tortoisesvn, merge-conflict-resolution

I work on a branch from a trunk. Before merging it back to the trunk, I update the branch. After resolving the update-conflicts, the branch is merged with the trunk.

Do you know if conflicts occur during merge, even after resolving the update-conflicts?

Comment: Sure. Nothing prevents you from editing the same lines of code in different branches.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. So you made a branch -> Made your changes -> Updated your branch (from the trunk) to make sure you were up to date -> resolved any merge conflicts -> then merged back into the trunk... What part are you having trouble with? Are you asking that even after resolving the update conflicts when you were making sure you were up to date, whether or not you would get any more conflicts when merging back into the trunk?

Comment: If you're asking if merge conflicts occur when you're merging back into the trunk, the answer is yes. They _can_ occur, doesn't mean it will though, especially if you've ensured you were up to date prior to merging. It's smart enough to handle a _lot_ of scenarios, but it won't do all of them automatically. Depends on the amount/complexity of the changes.

Comment: Yes, that was my question, whether during the merge to the trunk (even after resolving the update conflicts) brings conflicts.